# The upper bound of hyperbolic cosine function in complex plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, hyperbolic-geometry, special-functions

I want to find the upper bound of the following function :
\begin{equation}
M(\lambda)=\max _{E \in \mathbb{C}}\left|L_{+}-L_{-}\right|
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& 4 \cosh \left(L_{+}\right)=\left|E^2+i \lambda E-4\right|+\left|E^2+i \lambda E\right| \\
& 4 \cosh \left(L_{-}\right)=\left|E^2-i \lambda E-4\right|+\left|E^2-i \lambda E\right|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ is a postive constant. Can anyone give the specific form  of $M(\lambda)$?

Comment: Probably this maximum is achieved where $L_+=0$ or $L_-=0$, i.e. at $E = \pm \frac{i}{2} \lambda \pm \sqrt{4- \frac{\lambda^2}{4}}$, but please check.

Comment: Thank you! we believe that  the maximum is achieved where $L_{-}=0$
, but we have no proof of this.